# A characterization of distinguished triangles in triangulated categories.

Tags: homological-algebra, triangulated-categories

Let $\mathscr{D}$ be a triangulated category. Let $$X \longrightarrow Y \longrightarrow Z \longrightarrow X[1]$$ 
be a triangle (not necessarily distinguished). We call it special if for each $E \in \mathscr{D}$ the induced long sequence of abelian groups $$\cdots Hom(E,X) \rightarrow Hom(E,Y) \rightarrow Hom(E,Z) \rightarrow Hom(E,X[1]) \cdots $$
is exact. 
Since for each $E \in \mathscr{D}$ the functor $Hom(E,-)$ is homological, distinguished triangles are special.
But is it true that special triangles are distinguished? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 11):

No, for instance if you multiply one of the maps in a distinguished triangle by minus one, then the resulting triangle will still be special but need no longer be distinguished.

Comment: See also here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/10187/exactness-in-triangulated-categories-is-reflected-by-hom-functor?rq=1